# Are coroutines just syntactic sugar around completion handlers?

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, kotlin, coroutine

Are coroutines just syntactic sugar around completion blocks and completion blocks will be created under the hood? Or is the concept of coroutines much more complex and broad then just compiler trick aka syntactic sugar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not just syntactic sugar, not at all. Coroutines **do not block** threads, they just **suspend** execution, thus they encourage **non-blocking** concurrent programming.

Coroutines do not rely on features of the operating system or the JVM (e.g. they are not mapped to native Threads). Instead, coroutines and `suspend` functions particularly are transformed by the compiler producing a **state machine** capable of handling suspensions in general and passing around suspending coroutines keeping their state. This is enabled by **[Continuations](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.experimental/-continuation/index.html)**, which are added as a parameter to each and every suspending function by the compiler; this technique is called “Continuation-passing style”.

For details please have a look at https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/kotlin-coroutines-informal.md

Comment: so completionBlocks won't be created under the hood like instead of ``func processImageData() async -> Image { ... }`` will be this ``func processImageData(completionHandler: (result: Image) -> Void) { ... }``?

Comment: ``Continuation``s are added to ``suspend`` functions: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/kotlin-coroutines-informal.md#continuation-passing-style

Comment: I still have a feeling that these coroutines are just nothing special other than syntactic sugar around completion blocks/lambdas, but implicitly calling the lambda/block on other thread.
Is it any different from async/await stuff from C#?

Comment: The concept is very old and not dedicated to Kotlin. Of course there are many different languages supporting it.

Comment: As you can read here "The first class of motivating use cases for coroutines are *asynchronous computations* (handled by async/await in C# and other languages)". So yes, it's similar. But the good thing is, Kotlin does not enforce any specific style like async/await in C#, you can also implement your own stuff, work with promises, actors, whatsoever. This here is another interesting document, I'd suggest to you: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/kotlin-coroutines-informal.md

Comment: while aRead/aWrite are special suspending functions which implicitly receive continuations (**continuations** are ``just generic callbacks``)

Comment: in case  you are curious look at my answer or just listen to that podcast :)

Answer (score 2):

No, coroutines are not syntactic sugar. You can think of coroutines as of functions that can interact with the caller. When you call a normal function, say `foo` you pass control to `foo` and have to wait until `foo` either completes or throws exception. Coroutines are functions which can pass control back to caller, and caller can decide whether coroutine should continue and *when* and *how* coroutine should continue. This gives opportunity to implement things which are special language constructs in other languages:

- Generators (aka `yield` keyword) like in C# and JavaScript. Caller continues execution of coroutine when a user wants new value from iterator. Coroutine passes back to caller by calling `yield()` function, which also passes some value to caller.
- Async/await like in C# and JavaScript. Caller continues execution when Future (similar to Task or Promise) gets resolved. Coroutine passes back to caller by calling `await()` function. Caller passes value to coroutine when Future gets resolved and coroutine observes this value as a result of `await()` call.
- Goroutines/channels in Go.

Unlike C#, JavaScript or Go, Kotlin does not implement any of these features in special syntax. Instead, Kotlin provides only `suspend fun` syntax, and then you can implement these features yourself (or get existing one from corresponding library called `kotlinx.coroutines`).

Comment: After diving into some source code, I suspect that implementing a coroutine cannot be done without mobbing with the compiler. Kotlin uses intrinsic implementations to achieve suspension and continuation, which is kinda bummer as Kotlin tried to avoid using the syntactic coroutine to leave some space for third parties but actually ended up with intrinsic methods that third parties normally really don't want to mess with.

Answer (score 2):

Corutines are syntactic sugar around asyncronous procedures, or, better say, Actors, which are repeatable asynchronous procedures.

Comment: and completion handlers are asynchronous procedures.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting article mentioning implementing async/await in their system: http://joeduffyblog.com/2015/11/19/asynchronous-everything/

> Along with this, we added the await and async keywords. A method could be marked async:
>
> async int Foo() { ... }
>
> All this meant was that it was allowed to await inside of it:
>
> async int Bar() {
>       int x = await Foo();
>       ...
>       return x * x;
>   }
>
> Originally this was merely syntactic sugar for all the callback goop above, like it is in C#. Eventually, however, we went way beyond this, in the name of performance, and added lightweight coroutines and linked stacks.